# How to properly structure my java code?

Tags: java, android

I am creating an android app.  It is my first "real" android app that I'm creating and I'm also new to Java.  I have never created any program with OOP before so I'm a little confused with the structure of things.  I have some PHP, experience but I initially learned to program with Turbo Pascal which was procedural (inline?).

Anyway...  Here is the situation:

1. Main Activity - This is the activity for controlling the actual Android app that I have.
2. class ScoreClock - This is where i have the following methods:

   ```
   public ScoreClock // initialize all the fields(variables) within the ScoreClock class.
   public getMinutes(long ms)  // take ms remaining and calculate minutes left.
   public getSeconds(long ms)  // take ms remaining and calculate seconds left.
   ```

Now...  I'm thinking of adding `public void updateBoard()` which would be for updating all of the values to the actual scoreboard.  What I'm confused with is...  Should the updateBoard() method go into the MainActivity.java file or the ScoreClock.java file?

The updateBoard method will be accessing the android fields/variables and changing the values of TextViews and such, so I'm thinking that it should be placed in MainActivity.java.

Could someone please clarify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code to update UI elements goes in the Activity or View itself. You can't access any of that from the POJO. It sounds like you, like so many, are trying to make a game. I would suggest you learn Java first, then Android, THEN try to make a game. Don't start with something as complicated as a game.

Comment: I'm not creating a game.  Actually the app itself is quite simple.  It is a scoreboard app for basketball.  So click the score and it increments.  Hold it to reset a value.  Clock counts down from 8 minutes to 0 and buzzes when done.

Comment: I think it might be simpler for you to use the [CountDownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) class. It has a callback you could use to update the UI, and then you can just handle the score. You should be able to do it with a single activity and no other classes.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start is with a Diagram.

I imagine your activity class is quite long and complex, from the information you have given in your question, i'm guessing that you have some sort of game board, that sounds like a potential item to refactor.

try this book http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfdp/ while it is not the best or most definitive guide to design it offers good entry level information and help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you started up a bit too far ahead, browse a little through oop, separation of concerns and mvc; anyway,given your question - the updateBoard() method should not be in your ScoreClock class, it should be in your Activity class which plays the controller in this case.

Comment: I'm somewhat familiar with the MVC architecture but have only hacked my way through PHP scripts involving OOP/MVC.  So, wasn't really sure how to set it up in the first place.

Comment: have a look at this link, it might clear out some things for you:      http://mindtherobot.com/blog/675/android-architecture-message-based-mvc/